# C# How to call function from C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have the following code that is implemented in a dll file

```cpp
typedef  signed __int16 TS_ELEMENT;
typedef  TS_ELEMENT *   TS_DATA;
LIBTERAVIEW_API TS_RES tsRead(TS_DATA buffer);
```

I would like to call this function in my C# program and use it in order to see data that is printed from it. I have read about unmanaged structures and importing functions from DLLs; however, I am not able to figure out the syntax of how to do this in my code. I have generated the following codes based on my readings on this topic:

```cs
[DllImport("libteraview.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void tsStart();

[DllImport("libteraview.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern byte* tsRead(byte* buffer);`
```

The first one works however, I am not able to get the second method to run and read data as it always gives me an Unhandled Exception error.

I would appreciate any help on how to get this `tsRead()` function imported from a DLL.

Comment: If `buffer` is supposed to point to one `__int16`, declare it as `ref short buffer`. If to an array of `__int16`, declare it as `[MarshalAs(LPArray), In, Out] short[] buffer`. If you want manual pointer arithmetic, `IntPtr buffer`. Regarding the return value, that depends on what `TS_RES` is.

Comment: Judging from the company's manual, it should be int tsRead(short[] buffer).  Where the buffer you pass must be large enough to store the camera image, sizeX * sizeY.  Check the return value for error codes, 0 == "no error".  Do contact the company's technical support if you still have problems.  Note that it is very likely that they already have a .NET wrapper available, you'll surely prefer it.  Call them to find out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. I used the following line `public static extern int tsRead([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray),In,Out] short[] buffer)`. This worked perfectly and I am now able to call the function and see the data being captured after creating a buffer with the correct size. I appreciate your help with this.